# Where is the Neo4J log file neo4j.log on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j

I'm running Neo4J on an AWS EC2 instance using the Neo4J default AMI instance and I can't find the `neo4j.log` file anywhere. I have the `debug.log` and the `security.log` and I could set up the `query.log`, which are all in `/var/log/neo4j/` folder but there is no `neo4j.log` file. Where to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Neo4j Operations Manual states, in different places:

- ["cloud images are based on the standard Neo4j Debian package"](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/cloud-deployments/cloudVms/#_basics_and_file_locations), and
- `neo4j.log is` [Not written for Debian and RPM packages](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/monitoring/logging/general-logging/#general-logging-log-files), and
- ["To view the neo4j.log for Debian and RPM, use `journalctl --unit=neo4j`"](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations-locations)

So, the `neo4j.log` data is not written to a text file for Debian (and RPM), but you can still access the equivalent log data via the `journalctl` command.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any way I could trace this log live and restart Neo4J in case there are errors with heap memory and it's not restarting on its own?